# $e^{Log_*(z^k)} = e^{kLog_*(z)} $?

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function, branch-cuts

Please let me know if this is a duplicate. I couldn't find any related questions so far.

In my class, we often find the branch cut of $f(z) = z^k$ by equating the function to $f(z) = e^{Log(z^k)} = e^{kLog(z)}$.

An example can be seen here (prof's note):
[image]

However, we cannot say ${Log(z^k)} = {kLog(z)}$ (for example, take $Log_\pi ((-1)^2)$).

I've been trying to prove the equation $e^{Log_*(z^k)} = e^{kLog_*(z)} $ or to find the condition under which it holds.

Following is my unsuccessful proof so far:

Let $z = re^{i\theta}, r\in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{R^-}, \theta \in \mathbb{R}$.

Hence, $z^k = r^ke^{ik\theta}$

$Log_\pi (z^k) = \ln|r^ke^{ik\theta}| + iArg_\pi(r^ke^{ik\theta})$

$kLog_\pi (z) = k\left(\ln|re^{i\theta}| + iArg_\pi(re^{i\theta})\right) =k\ln (r) + ikArg_\pi(re^{i\theta}) $

Rasing $e$ to each power:

$e^{Log_\pi (z^k)} = e^{\ln|r^ke^{ik\theta}| + iArg_\pi(r^ke^{ik\theta})} =  |r^ke^{ik\theta}|\cdot e^{iArg_\pi(r^ke^{ik\theta})}$

$e^{kLog_\pi (z)} = e^{k\ln (r) + ikArg_\pi(re^{i\theta})} = r^k \cdot e^{ikArg_\pi(re^{i\theta})} =r^k \cdot e^{ik\theta'}$ where $\theta + 2\pi n =\theta'\in(\pi, 3\pi], n\in \mathbb{Z}$

I don't know how to go from here. Can somebody please help?

Or can you just tell me under what condition the equation in title holds?

---

Edit: I asked my prof the same and his reply was:

> This is almost never true. It is true only if $k$ is an integer and you use $log$ instead of $Log$. It is also true that the functions $αLog(z)$ and $Log(zα)$ differ by a constant.

But how did he conclude $(-i)^{i-1} = e^{(i-1)Log(-1)}$ like in his note above?

Comment: The equation in the title is always true (at least with the natural base).  Its generalization (used in the prof's note) is how we define complex exponentiation.

Comment: I don't know if it's a common notation, but it looks like you're defining $$\operatorname{Log}_b(z) = \ln|z| + i\operatorname{Arg}_b(z) \\ \operatorname{Arg}_b(z) \in (b, b+2\pi]\quad \text{ s.t. } \quad z = |z|\exp(i\operatorname{Arg}_b(z))$$ Is that correct? (Going into your question, I had assumed $b$ was some sort of base choice rather than a branch choice)

Comment: Correct. I am following the convention of [this book](https://www.perlego.com/book/811367/fundamentals-of-complex-analysis-with-applications-to-engineering-science-and-mathematics-pearson-new-international-edition-pdf).

Comment: I added my prof's response to this question. Please refer to Edit in the post! We will figure this out! I will keep bugging my prof as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

We often **define** the complex exponential [subject to the choice of branch, and using your collection of branches,] by $$z^w := \exp(w\operatorname{Log}_bz)$$ and as the definition of $\operatorname{Log}_b$, we also always have $z = \exp(\operatorname{Log}_bz)$.  When you put those two properties together, you have for any complex $z,w$ (with $z$ nonzero), $$\exp(w\operatorname{Log}_bz) := z^w = \exp(\operatorname{Log}_b(z^w)).$$

When $w$ is an integer, this will be consistent with the algebraic definition since a integral multiple of an integral multiple of $2\pi$ will be an integral multiple of $2\pi$.

When $z>0$ and $w$ are real, then you need to choose the principal branch to find a consistent result to real exponentiation.

---

With the above definition in mind, the equation in your professor's notes, $$(-i)^{i-1} = e^{(i-1)\operatorname{Log}_b(-i)},$$ is just a trivial application of the definition of complex exponentiation.